# Django Admin Not Using ModelManager's create Method

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Am I interpreting [the default behavior of the Django Admin site to not use the `ModelManager`'s `create` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4c2f546b55c029334d22e69bb29db97f9356faa3/django/forms/models.py#L322)? If so, how would I get this behavior?

My model has a custom Model manager with bespoke `create` method.

Answer (score 5):

Override the [`ModelAdmin.save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:
            obj.save()
        else:
            new_obj = MyModel.objects.create(name=obj.name, ...)
            obj.pk = new_obj.pk
```

Comment: This works well. Instead of listing fields as parameters you can also just pass `**form.cleaned_data`.